# How to cleartimeout a selected variable from multiple choices on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b1Lsp3y3/

Script:

```
...
$(this).parent().mouseover(function () {
    if (settings.pauseOnHover == 1) {
        clearInterval(po);
    }
}).mouseout(function () {
    po = setInterval(function () { AutoSlide($(this)) }.bind(this), settings.timeoutSet);
});
...
```

The issue I am having is when hovering over any of the slider it doesn't pause that one but instead both sliders starts to act randomly.

How can I update my script so if I hover over the first slider, it pauses that one only and the second slider continues and if I hover over the second slider, it pause that one only and first slider continues from where it was paused from, and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the mouseout callback function.

```
$(this).parent().mouseover(function () {
if (settings.pauseOnHover == 1) {
    clearInterval(po);
}
}).mouseout(function () {
    po = setInterval(function () { AutoSlide($(this)) }.bind(this), settings.timeoutSet);
}.bind(this)); // <<-- TRY THIS
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. I will accept your answer as it is a bit shorter :).

Answer (score 1):

can you please try like this;

```
  var _this = $(this);
    $(this).parent().mouseover(function () {
        if (settings.pauseOnHover == 1) {
            clearInterval(po);
        }
    }).mouseout(function () {
        po = setInterval(function () { AutoSlide($(_this)) }.bind(_this), settings.timeoutSet);
    });
```